# No records showing after successful connection to MongoDB in Robotframework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robotframework

I tried retrieving records from MongoDB from my Robotframework as below:

*** Test Cases ***
Connect-Disconnect
Connect To MongoDB   ${url}
${result} =    retrieve all mongodb records    {DBName}   {CollName}
Log Many    ${result}
Disconnect From MongoDB

The test is passing but it doesn't log any records.